# Buttons to pause and reset timer

Tags: java, button, timer, processing

I would like to add a button that pauses the timer running and another button that will reset the timer.

The code is below:

```
import processing.sound.*;
  void playSoundFile(String filename) {
  SoundFile player;
  player = new SoundFile(this, filename);
  player.play();
}
//load image 
PImage bg;
//store millis function 
int m = millis(); 
//also stores millis for later use
int startingTime;

void setup() {
size(410,308);
//load the background image and store it in the url variable 
String url = "http://yodas.ws/2007/11/keele1.JPG";
bg = loadImage(url,"jpg");
//stores the millis function
startingTime = millis();


}

void draw() {
//sets the background to the image that was loaded
background (bg);
//stores second, minute, hour
int s = second();
int m = minute();
int h = hour();
//stores and converts the second, minute and hour to string
String sec = str(s);
String minu = str(m);
String hr = str(h);
String time = hr + ":" + minu;
//displays the time variable
text (time, 300, 50);
//sets the colour of the text
fill(255,172,108);
//sets the text size to 32 pixels
textSize(32);

int seconds = (millis() - startingTime) / 1000;
   //divides seconds by 60 for a minute 
   int minutes = seconds / 60;
   //divides minutes by 60 for a hour 
   int hours = minutes/60;
   //multiplies minutes by 60 for seconds 
   seconds-=minutes * 60;
  //multiplies hours by 60 for minutes 
   minutes-=hours * 60;



   //causes a 10 second delay when user presses a key 
   if (keyPressed == true){
      playSoundFile("down.mp3");
      delay(10000);



   }


   //sets the colour of the text, displays text and text size 
   fill(255, 0, 0);
   fill(255,172,108);
   text((hours) + ":" + (minutes) + ":" + (seconds),20,50);
   textSize(32);


}


//void keyPressed(){
  //if (m < 0){
   // delay(1000);
 // }
//}
//reset timer 

  //resets the timer when the user clicks the mouse
  void mouseClicked(){
  if (m > 0) {
  startingTime = millis();
  //keyPressed();
  playSoundFile("down.mp3");

  };



};
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: I'd start by clearly representing the state of my timer : it's got a current time and an activation state (running/paused). There would be methods to retrieve and manipulate that state as I see fit, and I'd probably add some functionality helping me to retrieve the seconds/minutes/hours parts, or maybe a text representation of the time, but no GUI code. Then in my GUI class I'd have an instance of this timer, and I'd have my buttons change the state of the timer by invoking its functions.

Comment: Thanks for that Aaron but could you demonstrate that or help me with turn that into code as really have no idea forgive me I'm new to programming.